# String Interpolation with format variable

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I can do this:

```
var log = string.Format("URL: {0}", url);
```

or even like this

```
var format = "URL: {0}";
...
var log = string.Format(format, url);
```

I have a `format` defined somewhere else and use the `format` variable, not inline string.

In C# 6, this is seems impossible:

```
var format = $"URL: {url}"; // Error url does not exist
...
var url = "http://google.com";
...
var log = $format; // The way to evaluate string interpolation here
```

Is there anyway to use string interpolation with variable declared earlier?

C# 6 seems interpolate the string inline during compile time. However consider using this feature for localization, define a format in config or simply having a format `const` in a class.

Comment: You can't do that.  Just use `string.Format`.

Comment: You have to use 'the old way' you have been using or wrap it into private method.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, you can't use string interpolation with something other than a string literal as the compiler creates a "regular" format string even when you use string interpolation.

Because this:

```
string name = "bar";
string result = $"{name}";
```

is compiled into this:

```
string name = "bar";
string result = string.Format("{0}", name);
```

the string in runtime must be a "regular" format string and not the string interpolation equivalent.

You can use the plain old `String.Format` instead.

Comment: I agreed. I thought logically `"{name}"` to `"{0}"` mapping can be done in run-time at the first place but the `string.Format` parameters should be compiled inline. So I can't simply introduce new `{name2}` dynamically in variable.

Comment: but at least it should accept `const string`. The compiler then can find-out the `"{...}"` token and construct the `string.Format` parameters. Anyway, not a big deal.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN this would work *only* if the const was defined inside the method, so that the compiler could resolve (and validate) the placeholders. Otherwise, how could the compiler decide whether a *class-level* constant string was valid, if its placeholders existed only inside *methods*?

Answer (score 34):

One approach to work around that would be to use a lambda containing the interpolated string. Something like:

```
Func<string, string> formatter = url => $"URL: {url}";
...
var googleUrl = "http://google.com";
...
var log = formatter(googleUrl);
```

In C# 7.0, you could use a local function instead of a lambda, to make the code slightly simpler and more efficient:

```
string formatter(string url) => $"URL: {url}";
...
var googleUrl = "http://google.com";
...
var log = formatter(googleUrl);
```

Answer (score 5):

String interpolation is not library, but a compiler feature starting with C# 6.

The holes are not names, but expressions:

```
var r = new Rectangle(5, 4);
var s = $"Area: {r.Width * r.Height}":
```

How would you do that for localization, as you intend to?

Even `r` only exists at compile time. In IL it's just a position on the method's variable stack.

I've done what you intend to do for resources and configuration files.

Since you can only have a finite set of "variables" to substitute, what I did was have an array (or dictionary, if you prefer) and use a regular expression to replace the names in the holes with its index. What I did even allowed for format specifiers.

Comment: The localization part is `"area: "` in your example. However +1 for mention about expression.

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to be a comment to the answer from i3arnon but I do not have the reputation :-( :
But for those who come to this old thread, in string.Format the format can be a variable:

```
string name = "bar";
string format = "{0}";
string result = string.Format(format, name);
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

You can with the right Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/InterpolatedStringFormatter

```cs
var mystring = "a thing(and something {other})";
Console.WriteLine(mystring.Interpolate("else"));
```

Outputs:

```
a thing(and something else)
```

Answer (score 0):

More of an idea as opposed to an answer.

For the example shown in the question, you can do the following.

```
var format = "URL: ";
...
var url = "http://google.com";
...
var result= $"{format} {url}";
```

I have an actual project where I have to do something like this a lot:

```
var label = "Some Label";
var value = "SomeValue";

//both label & value are results of some logic

var result = $"{label}: {value}";
```

Answer (score -6):

It seems that you can do it like this:

```
var googleUrl = "http://google.com";
var url = $"URL: {googleUrl}";

System.Console.WriteLine(url);
```

You can check for more details in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx