# Insert dynamic number format into interpolated string

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

C# 6.0 brings this nifty new formatting operation indicated by a `$`

Instead of doing this

```
String lastName = "Doena";
String firstName = "DJ";

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{1} {0}", lastName, firstName));
```

you can do this

```
Console.WriteLine($"{firstName} {lastName}");
```

But what about number formats. What if I have this:

```
Decimal price = 9999.95m;
Decimal freebie = 0;

const String format = "#,##0.##";

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:" + format + "}\t{1:" + format + "}", price, freebie));
```

I tried this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{price:"{format}"}\t{freebie:"{format}"}");
```

and this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{price:{format}}\t{freebie:{format}}");
```

and this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{price:format}\t{freebie:format}");
```

But they either not even compile or do not bring the hoped result.

Any ideas?

**Edit** Howwie's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772055/insert-dynamic-format-into-interpolated-string#comment66838596_39772055) seems to be the reasonable way to go here:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{price.ToString(format)}\t{freebie.ToString(format)}");
```

Comment: You can't do that, basically. You'll have to call `string.Format` explicitly.

Comment: This isn't related to C# 6.0. It's like asking why you can't do `{0:{1}}` in previous versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Interpolation with format variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360434/string-interpolation-with-format-variable)

Comment: @Sinatr: I don't think it's a duplicate of that. That suggests that the *data to be formatted* is dynamic, whereas this is only about the format specifier being dynamic.

Comment: You could instead do `Console.WriteLine($"{price.ToString(format)}\t{freebie.ToString(format)}");`

Comment: I would say in this case its better to format each variable individually, then concatenate the formatted strings. The interpolated version is much more difficult to read in this case. If the string were a bit more complex than just `price tab freebie` then I'd use an interpolated string with the formatted variables.

Comment: @ChrisChilvers This was just an example, not actual production code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Howwie's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772055/insert-dynamic-format-into-interpolated-string#comment66838596_39772055) seems to be the reasonable way to go here:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{price.ToString(format)}\t{freebie.ToString(format)}");
```