# C# Format String

Tags: c#

C# can format a string e.g. $"string {a} {b} {c}" to substitute the variables a, b and c into the string.

```
    var a = "string1";
    var b = "string2";
    var c = "string3";
    var d = $"string {a} {b} {c}";    // become "string string1 string2 string3"
```

Is is possible to store the format string to a variable so that I can create the string template dynamically.

```
    var a = "string1";
    var b = "string2";
    var c = "string3";
    var template = "string {a} {b} {c}";

    var d = $template;  // Can I do this?
```

Thank you!

Comment: You'll have to use `string.Replace` e.g. `template.Replace("{a}", a).Replace("{b}", b).Replace("{c}", c)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String Interpolation with format variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360434/string-interpolation-with-format-variable) This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255291/4728685) might be helpful as well

Answer (score 2):

You should use `string.Format`:

```
var a = "string1";
var b = "string2";
var c = "string3";

var template = "string {0} {1} {2}";

var d = string.Format(template, a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 2):

yes very possible you are taking one string and formatting it to fill in variables just like with any language.

In C# it can be done like this

```
var a = "string1"; // first string
var b = "string2"; // second string
var c = "string3"; // third string
var d = "string {0} {1} {2}"; // string to format (fill with variables)

// formatting the string 
var template = string.Format(d, a, b, c);

// output -> "string string1 string2 string3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by using `String.Format`.

```
var a = "string1";
var b = "string2";
var c = "string3";
var template = "string {0} {1} {2}";

var d = String.Format(template, a,b,c);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good candidate is `string.Format`, but you could also use the fancy `FormattableStringFactory`.

```
var a = "string1";
var b = "string2";
var c = "string3";
var template = "string {0} {1} {2}"; //Please note, not {a}, but {0}

var str = string.Format(template, a, b, c); // Preferred

// From System.Runtime.CompilerServices
var str2 = FormattableStringFactory.Create(template, new object[] { a, b, c });
```

If you want to keep '`{a}`' (not '`{0}`') then `string.Replace` is here to help.

```
var d = template
       .Replace('{a}', a);
       .Replace('{b}', b);
       .Replace('{c}', c);
```