# Is there a way to replace the arguments in a string multiple times?

Tags: c#, string

I'm declaring a string at initialisation as follows

```
string a = string.Format("Hello {0}", "World.");
```

Is there a way to subsequently replace the zeroth argument for something else?

If there's no obvious solution, does anybody know of a better way to address the issue. For context, at initialisation I create a number of strings. The text needs to be updated as the program proceeds. I could create a structure comprising an array of strings and an array of objects and then build the final string as required, but this seems ugly, particularly as each instance could have a different number of arguments.

For example,

```
public class TextThingy
{
   List<String> strings;
   List<String> arguments;

   ...

   public string ToString()
   {
      return strings[0] + arguments [0] + strings [1] ...
   }
```

I've tried this, but to no avail.

```
string b = string.Format(a, "Universe.");
```

I guess that the argument {0} once populated is then baked into the string that one time.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Comment: `string b = string.Format("Hello {0}", "Universe.");`?

Comment: `string fmt = "Hello {0}";` then `string a = string.Format(fmt, "World");` then `string b = string.Format(fmt, "Universe");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Format String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61515447/c-sharp-format-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the format string to a variable like this?
Would that work? If not, please add some more info for us.

```
string fmt = "Hello {0}";

string a = string.Format(fmt, "World.");

string b = string.Format(fmt, "Universe.");
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks. I didn't realise it could just be left empty initially.

Answer (score 0):

try string replace, like ...

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("11223344");

string myString =
    sb
      .Replace("1", string.Empty)
      .Replace("2", string.Empty)
      .Replace("3", string.Empty)
      .ToString();
```