# Replace parameters in URL parameter for HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, string, url, dotnet-httpclient

How to replace a parameter in C# HttpRequestMessage URL?

I have the following code,

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://MyService/Ids/63847/create"))
```

I want to replace 63847 with something like {0}, and have it set up dynamically. Is there a way to do that in C#?

Comment: With string interpolation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String Interpolation with format variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360434/string-interpolation-with-format-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    new HttpMethod("POST"), 
    string.Format("http://MyService/Ids/{0}/create", 12345)
))
```